# Stop Worksheet change event firing when accessing database

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba macro that imports data from a spreadsheet and fills a sheet called "Validation" with data from the database. I am trying to set up a worksheet change event that when the data is changed in the sheet then it will update the database with the new values.

This works at the moment but the problem I am having is that when I originally get the data for that sheet from the database the worksheet change event is firing which causes an error.

Is there any way to stop the change even firing when filling the sheet  and only when something is actually manually changed in the sheet ?

Sorry if my explanation is not every good. If you need any more information please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 Application.EnableEvents =False
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your import starts, add this line:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and after this event (and in case of an error!):

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is `Application.EnableEvents = False`. This will stop events from firing until the code encounters `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Depending upon how you import the data, you might set the switch in the importing procedure or create a little macro which you run manually.

Another possibility might be to use the Selection_Change event. This might be possible if data are pasted. In that case the Selection would comprise of many cells. You might turn off events when the selection comprises of more than one cell.

The same idea might be possible without switching off events, just by letting the Change event skip its function when the selection is greater than 1 cell. Bear in mind that the Change_Event would treat the ActiveCell as its `Target`.